# How to display all categories with some products each in Opencart 1.5?

Tags: php, opencart

I asked this over in the Opencart forums but no luck yet, so thought I'd try here.

*How can I display all the categories of products with some number of products from each category on one page?*  Like this:

```
Category 1
Item 1
Item 2

Category 2
Item 3
Item 4

Category 3
Item 5
Item 6
```

I think I need to copy and modify the category.php controller and category.tpl template files, but I'm not sure what changes to make to them.  If I could get help with the controller I could probably figure out the template on my own.

Not sure how helpful this will be here, but here's the controller file:

```
<?php 
class ControllerProductCategory extends Controller {  
public function index() { 
    $this->language->load('product/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $this->load->model('tool/image'); 

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
    } else {
        $sort = 'p.sort_order';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $order = $this->request->get['order'];
    } else {
        $order = 'ASC';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
    } else { 
        $page = 1;
    }   

    if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
        $limit = $this->request->get['limit'];
    } else {
        $limit = $this->config->get('config_catalog_limit');
    }

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home'),
        'separator' => false
    );  

    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $path = '';

        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

        foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
            if (!$path) {
                $path = $path_id;
            } else {
                $path .= '_' . $path_id;
            }

            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text'      => $category_info['name'],
                    'href'      => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path),
                    'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
                );
            }
        }       

        $category_id = array_pop($parts);
    } else {
        $category_id = 0;
    }

    $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

    if ($category_info) {
        $this->document->setTitle($category_info['name']);
        $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
        $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];

        $this->data['text_refine'] = $this->language->get('text_refine');
        $this->data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');         
        $this->data['text_quantity'] = $this->language->get('text_quantity');
        $this->data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
        $this->data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
        $this->data['text_price'] = $this->language->get('text_price');
        $this->data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
        $this->data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
        $this->data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));
        $this->data['text_display'] = $this->language->get('text_display');
        $this->data['text_list'] = $this->language->get('text_list');
        $this->data['text_grid'] = $this->language->get('text_grid');
        $this->data['text_sort'] = $this->language->get('text_sort');
        $this->data['text_limit'] = $this->language->get('text_limit');

        $this->data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
        $this->data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
        $this->data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
        $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        if ($category_info['image']) {
            $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height'));
        } else {
            $this->data['thumb'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['description'] = html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $this->data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $this->data['categories'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts(array('filter_category_id' => $result['category_id']));

            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'  => $result['name'] . ' (' . $product_total . ')',
                'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '_' . $result['category_id'] . $url)
            );
        }

        $this->data['products'] = array();

        $data = array(
            'filter_category_id' => $category_id, 
            'sort'               => $sort,
            'order'              => $order,
            'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
            'limit'              => $limit
        );

        $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($data); 

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
            } else {
                $image = false;
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }   

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
            } else {
                $tax = false;
            }               

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }

            $this->data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
            );
        }

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $this->data['sorts'] = array();

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_default'),
            'value' => 'p.sort_order-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_asc'),
            'value' => 'pd.name-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_name_desc'),
            'value' => 'pd.name-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=pd.name&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_asc'),
            'value' => 'p.price-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=ASC' . $url)
        ); 

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_price_desc'),
            'value' => 'p.price-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.price&order=DESC' . $url)
        ); 

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_desc'),
            'value' => 'rating-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=DESC' . $url)
        ); 

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_rating_asc'),
            'value' => 'rating-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=rating&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_asc'),
            'value' => 'p.model-ASC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=ASC' . $url)
        );

        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_model_desc'),
            'value' => 'p.model-DESC',
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=p.model&order=DESC' . $url)
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        $this->data['limits'] = array();

        $this->data['limits'][] = array(
            'text'  => $this->config->get('config_catalog_limit'),
            'value' => $this->config->get('config_catalog_limit'),
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=' . $this->config->get('config_catalog_limit'))
        );

        $this->data['limits'][] = array(
            'text'  => 25,
            'value' => 25,
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=25')
        );

        $this->data['limits'][] = array(
            'text'  => 50,
            'value' => 50,
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=50')
        );

        $this->data['limits'][] = array(
            'text'  => 75,
            'value' => 75,
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=75')
        );

        $this->data['limits'][] = array(
            'text'  => 100,
            'value' => 100,
            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&limit=100')
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $product_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = $limit;
        $pagination->text = $this->language->get('text_pagination');
        $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url . '&page={page}');

        $this->data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

        $this->data['sort'] = $sort;
        $this->data['order'] = $order;
        $this->data['limit'] = $limit;

        $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/product/category.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());                                        
    } else {
        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_error'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('product/category', $url),
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

        $this->data['text_error'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

        $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/error/not_found.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in opencart 1.5.1.3 you can go to extensions > modules > category and add categories wherever you want.